# Windows 2008 R2 firewall is disabled after boot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

I have a server with Windows 2008 R2 and Windows Firewall enabled.

When the OS boots, the firewall is disabled and every incoming connection is blocked.

So in order to make the server available I have to enable the firewall again through the Windows control panel.

The firewall service is enabled and started on boot.

Any idea on what's wrong with it?

Comment: I'm don't why your system is blocking when firewall is disabled but is your Windows firewall set to start automatic in services?

Answer (score 2):

Check msconfig for an alternate start-up configuration.
Check the registry to see if someone has disabled the firewall.
Check that group policy is not disabling the service with rsop / gpresult.
Check that your IP matches the firewall profile settings (domain, public, etc.).
Finally, verify that another AV/IDS/IPS/etc. product is not taking over.

If nothing else has been configured, do a clean boot and:

1. Stop the firewall service.
2. Disabled the firewall service.
3. Reboot the server. Verify connectivity. (Everything should be wide open)
4. Enable the service.
5. Start the service.
6. Reboot the server. Verify connectivity. (Everything should NOT be wide open)